# Mongoose add the object without the values on mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this JS code, it`s a server that will have CRUD functions

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var options = {
  db: { native_parser: true },
  server: { poolSize: 5 }
};

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/agenda', options);

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var contatoSchema = new Schema({

    nome: String,
    telefones: [],
    createdOn: {type: Date, default: Date.now}

});

var Contato = mongoose.model("Contato", contatoSchema);

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.post('/adicionar', function(req, res){

    var contato = req.body;

    contato = new Contato({nome: contato.nome, telefones: contato.telefones});

    contato.save(function(err, data){
        if (err) console.log(err);

        else res.json(data);

    }); 

});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

when i try to add an object using the URL '/adicionar' on Postman:

```
{
  "nome": Vinicius,
  "telefones": [
    123456
  ]
}
```

he gives me this answer

```
{
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "57439973e033c9902174cad0",
  "createdOn": "2016-05-23T23:59:47.284Z",
  "telefones": []
}
```

the problem is that the function doesn`t pass the correct values on the fields 'nome' and 'telefone', but he creates the array 'telefones' on mongoDB, i have the database 'agenda' created too, and he also creates the collection 'contato'.

i tried to rewrite the code search for syntax errors, i think that the bodyParser or Express mondule isn`t working but i installed both on the folder.

Other note, when i change the values of nome: contato.nome, telefones: contato.telefones to nome: "vinicius", telefones: [1235312], and run the code as node application he creates the object in the mongo DB with these values.

Comment: What do you mean by the last paragraph? You run the code as a node application?

Comment: What client do you use in eclipse when it works? If you are using a rest client then you probably don't have postman set up with the correct body encoding.

Answer (score 0):

you need request as Json

```
{
  "nome": "Vinicius",
  "telefones": [
    123456
  ]
}
```

try define your Schema like this

```
var contatoSchema = new Schema({
    nome: String,
    telefones: [Number],
    createdOn: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

Comment: req.body is from body-parser node module

Comment: yes, req,body when you request via Postman. console.log(contato) before contato.save()

Comment: when i change to console.log(contato) and try to add an object on postman i got this answer on the log.
|
|
Example app listening on port 3000!
{ telefones: [],
  createdOn: 2016-05-24T01:56:17.321Z,
  _id: 5743b4c146b906701a6e5b86,
  nome: undefined,
  __v: 0 }
|
is this what you are looking for?

Comment: your req.body is missing nome and telefones value. that is reason, your mongoose working fine

Comment: Connection →keep-alive
Content-Length →96
Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
Date →Tue, 24 May 2016 02:10:21 GMT
ETag →W/"60-8QmwOIpgxpi9i1kxuOtD3w"
X-Powered-By →Express

Comment: may be. use app.use(bodyParser.json()) when you want to parse json request

Comment: when i change the else in my contato.save function to else console.log( req.body ); thats what i get
"Example app listening on port 3000!
{}"
so my req.body is empty but i dont even know why, becouse im setting the bodyparser in my code

Answer (score 0):

i was trying to pass the json object as a Text in postman
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmZgy.jpg
now the code is working, sorry for that